# select part of a string after certain number of special character

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` with a column

```
V1
a_b_c_las_poi 
a_b_c_kiosk_pran 
a_b_c_qwer_ok
```

I would like to add a new column to this `data.table` which does not include the last part of string after the "_".

**UPDATE**

So i would like the output to be

`a_b_c_las
a_b_c_kiosk
a_b_c_qwer`

Comment: After the first "_" or the last "_". It would be helpful if you gave the desired output here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `k` is the number of fields to keep:

```
k <- 2
DT[, V1 := do.call(paste, c(read.table(text=V1, fill=TRUE, sep="_")[1:k], sep = "_"))]
```

`fill=TRUE` can be omitted if all rows have the same number of fields.

**Note:** `DT` in a reproducible form is:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- data.frame(V1 = c("a_b_c_las_poi", "a_b_c_kiosk_pran", "a_b_c_qwer_ok"),
   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DT <- as.data.table(DF)
```

Comment: Very nice and general solution. Really helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
sub("(.*)_.*", "\\1", V1)
[1] "a_b_c_las"   "a_b_c_kiosk" "a_b_c_qwer"
```